# Modulo operation, the remainder of division of one number by another

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The equation is:

$241 \equiv_{N} 35$

I have no clue how to get value of $N$, any ideas?

Comment: The usual convention is that $N$ is a positive integer. Then the answers are $1,2,103,206$. If you allow negative integers (not common) then you get $4$ more.

Comment: Sorry for digging an old thread. I was wondering and came to conclusion that 1 and 2 aren't answers. They don't fulfill the equation.

Comment: It is not that old. The notation i a little weird, but it looks as if the question asks for all $N$ such that $241\equiv 35\pmod{N}$. Under the common convention that $$N$ is positive, $N$ is one of $1,2,103,206$. For example, $2$ is a possibility, since $2$ divides #241-35$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: In order to find $N$ you need to remember that if $a = b \pmod N$ then $N \mid a-b$, in your case $N \mid 241-35$, can you take over from here?

---

In your case $241-35 = 206$, so $N=206$. But as I told you before you need to find the $N$ values that divide $241-35$ and therefore $206$ and those are $103$ and $2$.

In conclusion $241 \equiv_{N} 35$ if $N=1, 2, 103, 206$.

Comment: I don't think I understand what does '|' stand for. Wolframalpha gives me 5 different values of N

Comment: It means $N$ divides $a-b$.

Comment: How do you explain those possible solutions: 206/5; 103/2; 206/3; 103; 206?

Comment: Added the complete answer to your question, read above.